# hiding element with document.getElementsByClassName using onclick method

Tags: javascript, php, html

I know, that there is similar topic, but knowledge from there just do not work for me.

So I want to make first div element 'disappear', when img is clicked.. the problem is, that I have second function on img and something won't work. To be more precise - functions like/displike works good.. so I think, that I do not pass parameter to function hide properly. And I don't have error in my console.

By the way - I used two functions in onclick on purpose, taking element by class name is also made on purpose, cause I have a few elements using same ID's.

Pasted fragment from my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide(clicked){
    var click = document.getElementsByClassName('clicked');
           for(var i = 0; i < click.length; i = i + 1) {
       click[i].style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>

<div class="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" id="single">
   <div class="buttons"><img  class="single-button-red" id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" src="red-button.png" onclick="dislike(this.id);hide(this.id);" /><img class="single-button-green" id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" src="green-button.png" onclick="like(this.id);hide(this.id);"/></div>
   <div class="single-content"><?php echo $user['name']. "<br />". $user['age']. " lat"."<br />".distance($row['latitude'], $row['longitude'], $user['latitude'], $user['longitude'])." km"; ?></div>
   <a href="/user.php?id=<?php echo $user['id']; ?>">
      <div class="user-img"></div>
   </a>
</div>
<?php
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('clicked');` doesn't seem to match anything

Comment: Yep, I see this. I am trying to 'reach' dynamic ID generated in class..

Comment: But it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

```
<img onClick='hideFunction(div_id)' source='path/to/img'>

<script type="text/javascript">
function hideFunction(div_id){
    var div = document.getElementsByid(div_id);
    div.style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. I am trying to 'reach' dynamic ID generated in class in this JS function.. and I have another functions there (like, dislike), which are working pretty good.